# For loop won't repeat itself

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this block and the for loop doesn't repeat even if the path has more than 2 files.. It executes only once and that's all.. What's the problem? How can I make it run for all files in the list?

```
list=$(find $path -type f \( -name "*.c" -or -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.cxx" -or -name "*.cc" \))
for file in "$list";do
    #commands
done
```

Comment: Putting the variable in quotes makes it one word.

Comment: Removing quotes from "$list" makes shell interpret filenames with spaces as 2+ files..
e.g (filename (copy).c is 2 files 1)filename  and 2) (copy).c) Thats why i have the double quotes on..

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the use of `find` entirely here (Assuming the only files with those extensions are regular files; no directories etc.), via `bash`'s [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html):

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
for file in "$path"/**/*.@(c|cpp|cxx|cc); do
    # commands
done
```

Comment: `zsh`  equivalent is `"$path"/**/*.(c|cpp|cxx|cc)(.)`; the trailing `(.)` means to only match regular files.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `$list` in quotes makes it just one word, so it doesn't loop.

But if you take out the quotes, it won't work properly if any of the filenames contain whitespace, since they'll be split into multiple words.

Instead of assigning to a variable, pipe the output to a `while read` loop.

```
find $path -type f \( -name "*.c" -or -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.cxx" -or -name "*.cc" \) | while read -r file
do
    # commands
done
```

Comment: In Bash you could use `shopt -s globstar` and loop using `for file in ./**/*.c ./**/*.cpp ./**/*.cxx ./**/*.cc` to avoid a slow `read` loop.

Comment: Using while read -r file limits me as i cant read any other variable within loop..

Comment: You can redirect the input of other `read` commands inside the loop.